# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've a Flutter App Project which contains levels of permission, so, my main objective with this is allow an manager delete a user, making him not allowed anymore to login, deleting from FirebaseAuth.

I've a permission called "Deactivated" to prevent the user from logging in, but i really want to remove from FirebaseAuth too.

The only way I've found is using the Firebase Cloud Functions, so I tried to do very similar to FlutterFire Docs

When i execute using PostMan, it works perfectly, the user test is deleted as expected:
METHOD: Post
Url: https://us-central1-<DATABASE_NAME>.cloudfunctions.net/deleteUserByEmail/
Body -> Raw:

```
{
    "userEmail": "test@gmail.com"
}
```

My index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUserByEmail = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const userEmail = request.body.userEmail;
        admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userEmail)
            .then(userRecord => {
                const uid = userRecord.uid
                return admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("Successfully deleted user");
                        response.status(200).send('Delete User');
                        return
                    })
            }).catch(error => {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', error.HttpsError);

            });
    } catch (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', "Error passing arguments into");
    }

})
```

Part of my code that calls the code Flutter code:

```
HttpsCallable callable =
          FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('deleteUserByEmail');
      try {
        final resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
          "userEmail" : userModel.email,
        });
      } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }
```

Once i tap the button, i receive this error code:

```
E/flutter (20323): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL
E/flutter (20323):
E/flutter (20323): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:653
E/flutter (20323): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:296
E/flutter (20323): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20323): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23
E/flutter (20323): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20323): #3      HttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49
E/flutter (20323): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20323):
E/flutter (20323): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:653
E/flutter (20323): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:296
E/flutter (20323): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20323): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23
```

After some research I've found that some people had that problem when their code wasn't inside a tryCatch block, but mine was since ever...

I've tried to start admin.initializeApp() parsing the credentials and databaseURL even though my FlutterFire CLI is configured, but didn't work too.